2018: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Psychology & Neuroscience breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         10
Users destroyed                                   1          0
Users deleted                                     2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            89        187
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               42         69
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         36         90
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               42         80
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               112        730
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              243        714
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          0
Tag synonyms created                              4          0
Questions unprotected                             1          1
Questions reopened                               31          0
Questions protected                              16         20
Questions migrated                               26          0
Questions flagged⁴                                3        327
Questions closed                                558         43
Question flags handled⁴                         267         63
Posts unlocked                                    1         13
Posts undeleted                                  17         18
Posts locked                                      1         40
Posts deleted⁵                                  230        673
Posts bumped                                      0        105
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               19          0
Comments flagged                                  0        142
Comments deleted⁶                               689        458
Comment flags handled                            63         79
Answers flagged                                  11        320
Answer flags handled                            314         17
All comments on a post moved to chat              3          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Psychology & Neuroscience without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁴ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Wishing you all a happy new year...
